# IOS Ventura Safari 16.3 position fixed elements goes above scroll bar

Tags: css, html, browser-compatibility, mac, ios

IOS Ventura Safari  16.3 whenever I create a position fixed element with 100% width, It goes above or bellow the scroll bar as well.
this is easy to recreate.

```
.anyelement {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  left:0;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

In all other browsers will show this element on the right corner just before the scroll bar. But only in safari latest versions the element will be like overflowing the viewport.
[image: Screen shot taken from the Browser stack]